# Difficulties With Button Functionality

Tags: html

Good Day,

I am working through freecodecamp and am currently grappling with the quote generator problem. **I have run into a bit of an issue with getting functionality for me scripting a change when clicking the button**. Basically I have my own code which I'll post below, but also trying to simply copy and paste the code from them I am still unable to get functionality in my button.

I am sure it's an honest and easy mistake but hopefully that should make it all the easier to resolve :) Let me know if you have any questions and I genuinely appreciate it!

(please note I simply want to change the display message upon clicking the button)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
       $(".message").html("New Message");
     });
   });
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
     <button type="button" id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-   primary">Generate New Quote</button>
</div>

<div class= "text-center">
  <div class = "message">
    Sample
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referencing jQuery?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? What do they say

Comment: works perfectly here.  https://jsfiddle.net/7wpvdgnb/ probably not loading jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, you are most likely not adding jQuery, yet you are attempting to use it (`$`). To confirm this, check your console. It's probably filled with `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Assuming you're using [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) as the [challenege](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-random-quote-machine) says in the objective, you can very quickly and easily include jQuery. To do so, just click the `settings cog` next to JS, use the `Quick-add` drop down, and select `jQuery`.

If you wish to include it manually (as you will most likely have to in future development) I recommend  [Drefetr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166552/6069012).

Comment: His answer worked but thanks for you following up too!

Answer (score 0):

There do not appear to be any major issues with the code (with respect to the logic, the editor may have rendered your formatting a little nastily).

Can you confirm that you have included the jQuery libraries within the header of your HTML document? e.g.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For more information: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: That fixed it perfectly. I feel like a total goof but thank you so much!